# How to disable scientific notation in ggvis?

Tags: r, ggvis

How can I disable the scientific format in the labels on this ggvis chart?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
tbl_df(cars) %>% mutate(speed=speed*100000000) %>% 
ggvis(~speed, ~dist) %>% scale_numeric('x', trans='log') %>% layer_points()
```

I have tried with `options("scipen"=100, "digits"=4)` but it didn't work.

Comment: `add_axis("x", format = "d")` (it uses [D3 formatters](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Formatting))

Comment: Thanks, any alternatives? I actually have a sort of template function, and if I set `format='d'` then it returns `NA` in all those charts where I have a character on the `x` axis.
Your comment solves the reproducible example though. If you post it as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: You'll probably have to test for the column type (continuous vs discrete) and then make the `format` setting optional (break the pipe, do the test, optionally add the axis, continue the pipe).